# Is there a way to make this bayesian graph in latex prettier?

Tags: graph, latex

Is there a way to make the graph on the left more like the one on the right? I wish it was more circular and the nodes were ellipse shaped. Then any suggestion to make the graph even cuter is welcome.

Here is my code:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance={25mm}, thick]
\node[main] (1) {x0};
\node[main] (2) [above right of=1] {x1};
\node[main] (3) [below right of=1] {x2}; 
\node[main] (4) [right of=2] {x3};
\node[main] (5) [right of=3] {x4}; 
\node[main] (6) [below right of=3] {x5};
\node[main] (7) [below right of=4] {x6}; 
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{center}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a node shape named `ellipse` that makes the node shaped like an ellipse. You can determine the size with `text width`, `inner sep` or `text height`. To make the nodes arranged really circular, you can define an empty center node and calculate the position each of the other nodes using an angle and all the same radius.

Example Code (I renamed the nodes because I found the indexing/labels confusing):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}

\tikzset{ellipsenode/.style={draw, ellipse, thick, text width=6ex, align=center, inner sep=3pt}}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance={25mm}, thick]
\node (center) [circle] {};
\node (x0) at ($(center)+(170:25mm)$)[ellipsenode] {x0};
\node (x1) at ($(center)+(120:25mm)$)[ellipsenode] {x1};
\node (x2) at ($(center)+(210:25mm)$)[ellipsenode] {x2}; 
\node (x3) at ($(center)+(60:25mm)$)[ellipsenode] {x3};
\node (x4) at ($(center)+(330:25mm)$)[ellipsenode] {x4}; 
\node (x5) at ($(center)+(270:25mm)$)[ellipsenode] {x5};
\node (x6) at ($(center)+(10:25mm)$)[ellipsenode] {x6}; 
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Now the hard part is making it cuter, because that might be a matter of taste. I guess some color won't hurt. For example, adding `ball color=blue!20, opacity=.7` to the `ellipsenode` style gives you this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A bit similar to @jf_ nice answer, juts without the extra step to define a central node. Instead you could directly place your nodes using polar coordinates.

Instead of the `center` environment, I would use `{\centering ...}` to avoid the extra vertical space.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\tikzset{main/.style={
  ellipse,
  minimum width=3em,
  draw
}} 

\begin{document}

{
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance={25mm}, thick]
\node[main] at (-0*51.4+180:2cm) {x0};
\node[main] at (-1*51.4+180:2cm) {x1};
\node[main] at (-2*51.4+180:2cm) {x2}; 
\node[main] at (-3*51.4+180:2cm) {x3};
\node[main] at (-4*51.4+180:2cm) {x4}; 
\node[main] at (-5*51.4+180:2cm) {x5};
\node[main] at (-6*51.4+180:2cm) {x6}; 
\end{tikzpicture} 
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, it is a very nice job!